# Play/Pause Button in Chromeless Youtube?

Tags: javascript, youtube

*The question is closely related to my past question here, but it is not the same.*

**Problem:** to add a Play/Pause button in Chromeless Youtube  here.

**Attack:** I added the below code like here (search "SERVERFAULT" in the code) or like below:

```
  var playingtimes = 0;

  function playPauseVideo(playingtimes) {
    if (playingtimes % 2 == 0){
      playVideo();
    }else{
      pauseVideo();
    }
    playingtimes += 1;
  }
```

Then, I added near the end:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="playPauseVideo(playingtimes);">Play/Pause</a>
```

**Error:** the button works like Play-button, because playingtimes is EVEN ie 0 all the time. Errror is in the playingtimes-variable.

**Question:** How can I add a Play/Pause Button to the Chromeless Youtube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the state of the player directly by using ytplayer.getPlayerState(), so you can make a simple function like this to do it:

```
function playPause() {
    if (ytplayer.getPlayerState() != 1) {
        // player is not playing, so tell it to play
        playVideo();
    } else {
        pauseVideo();
    }
}
```

The cool thing about a setup like this, it should also work if the video is ENDED or CUED.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this line into your code.  click the Play/Pause button a bunch of times and edit your question with the results.

```
alert("Value of 'playingtimes' global is " + playingtimes);
```

Place here:

```
  var playingtimes = 0;

      function playPauseVideo(playingtimes) {
        if (playingtimes % 2 == 0){
          playVideo();
        }else{
          pauseVideo();
        }
        playingtimes += 1;
        alert("Value of 'playingtimes' global is " + playingtimes);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **playingtimes** from function definition and from function call, then it will be used global variable **playingtimes** instead of local one with the same name which you defined inside the function. So your code will be:

```
var playingtimes = 0;
function playPauseVideo() {
```

and link to call it:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="playPauseVideo();">Play/Pause</a>
```